# R - read Excel file and switch variables into observations

Tags: r, excel, tidyr

I am struggling with some data transformation. I have some huge xlsx files with insurance data. The data is structured a little bit like a "pyramid". The first line represents the quarter in which the survey took place. The next line is a breakdown by age categories. There are 4 categories: in total values, up to 17, 18-64 and 65+. One sheet contains 4 quarters so basically 48 unique variables and the column with country names. One excel file contains 3 sheets (2016, 2017 and 2018). The screenshot (INPUT DATA) comes from a excel file where the name is "sick-leave blue collar workers". I have also two other files: "sick-leave worker" and "sick-leave self-employment". The goal is combine all three files and create a file with a structure like in the RESULT DATA. Could you please help me?

INPUT DATA:[image]

RESULT DATA: [image]

Comment: Where is the information on type of leave and group stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the `readxl` and `tidyr` packages from the [Tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/).  To make the script reproducible, I created an Excel version of the OP screen capture and saved it to my `stackoverflowAnswers` github repository. The script downloads the Excel file, reads it, and converts it to Tidy Data format.

```
# download Excel file from github repository

sourceFile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/stackoverflowanswers/master/data/soQuestion53446800.xlsx"
destinationFile <- "./soQuestion53446800.xlsx"
download.file(sourceFile,destinationFile,mode="wb")


library(readxl)
library(tidyr)

# set constants 
typeOfLeave <- "sick"
group <- "self employed"

# read date and extract the value
theDate <- read_excel(destinationFile,range="A2:A2",col_names=FALSE)[[1]]

# setup column names using underscore so we can separate key column into Sex and Age columns 
theCols <- c("Country","both_all","women_all","men_all","both_up to 17","women_up to 17","men_up to 17")
theData <- read_excel(destinationFile,range="A5:G9",col_names=theCols)

# use tidyr / dplyr to transform the data
theData %>% gather(.,key="key",value="Amount",2:7) %>% separate(.,key,into=c("Sex","Age"),sep="_") -> tidyData

# assign constants

tidyData$typeOfLeave <- typeOfLeave
tidyData$group <- group
tidyData$date <- theDate

tidyData
```

...and the output:

```
> tidyData
# A tibble: 30 x 7
   Country    Sex   Age   Amount typeOfLeave group         date               
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <dttm>             
 1 Total      both  all   151708 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 2 Afganistan both  all      269 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 3 Albania    both  all      129 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 4 Algeria    both  all      308 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 5 Andora     both  all      815 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 6 Total      women all    49919 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 7 Afganistan women all      104 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 8 Albania    women all       30 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
 9 Algeria    women all       18 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
10 Andora     women all      197 sick        self employed 2016-03-31 00:00:00
# ... with 20 more rows
```

## Key elements in the solution

Microsoft Excel is frequently used as a data entry and reporting tool, which leads people to structure their spreadsheets in hierarchical table formats like the one illustrated in the OP. This format makes the data difficult to use in R, because the column names represent combinations of information that is rendered hierarchically in table headers within the spreadsheet.

In this section we'll explain some of the key design elements in the solution to the problem posed in the OP, including:

1. Reading Excel files via exact cell references with `readxl::read_excel()`
2. Reading a single cell into a constant
3. Setting column names for ease of use with `tidyr::separate()`
4. Restructuring to narrow format Tidy Data
5. Assigning constants

### 1. Reading exact cell references

The OP question notes that there is a heading row containing a date for all the cells in a particular table. To simulate this in the sample spreadsheet I used to replicate the screen shot in the OP, I assigned the date of March 31, 2016 to cell `A2` of `Sheet 1` in an Excel workbook.

`readxl::read_excel()` enables reading of exact cell references with the `range=` argument.

### 2. Reading a constant from one cell

If we set the `range=` argument to a single cell and extract the cell with the `[[` form of the extract operator, the resulting object is a single element vector instead of a data frame. This makes it possible to use vector recycling to assign this value to the tidy data frame later in the R script.  
 Since everything in R is an object, we can use the `[[` extract operator on the result of `read_excel()` to assign the result to `theDate`.

```
theDate <- read_excel(theXLSX,range="A2:A2",col_names=FALSE)[[1]]
```

### 3. Setting column names for ease of use with `tidyr::separate()`

One of the characteristics that makes the original spreadsheet messy as opposed to [Tidy Data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) is the fact that each column of data represents a combination of `Sex` and `Age` values.

The desired output data frame includes columns for both `Sex` and `Age`, and therefore we need a way to extract this information from the column names. The `tidyr` package provides a function to support this technique, the `separate()` function.

To facilitate use of this function, we assign column names with an underscore separator to distinguish the `Sex` and `Age` components in the column names.

```
    theCols <- c("Country","both_all","women_all","men_all","both_up to 17","women_up to 17","men_up to 17")
```

### 4. Restructuring the data to narrow format Tidy Data

The key step in the script is a sequence of Tidyverse functions that takes the data frame read with `read_excel()`, uses `tidyr::gather()` on columns 2 - 7 to create one row per unique combination of Country, Sex, and Age, and then splits the resulting `key` column into the `Sex` and `Age` columns.

```
theData %>% gather(.,key="key",value="Amount",2:7) %>% separate(.,key,into=c("Sex","Age"),sep="_") -> tidyData
```

Data left of the underscore is assigned to the `Sex` column, and right of the underscore is assigned to `Age`. Note that the OP doesn't specify how the totals should be handled in the output. Since `total` doesn't make sense as a value for `Sex`, I used `Both` in its place. Similarly, for `Age` I assigned `total` as `All`.

### 5. Assigning constants

The OP does not explain where the constants `sick` and `group` are sourced, so I assigned them as constants at the start of the program. If these are included in the hierarchical part of the spreadsheet, they can easily be read using the technique I used to extract the date from the spreadsheet.

Once the data is in tidy format, we add the remaining constants via the assignment operator, taking advantage of [vector recycling](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules) in R.

```
tidyData$typeOfLeave <- typeOfLeave
tidyData$group <- group
tidyData$date <- theDate
```

## Additional considerations

If the `total` values are not required in the output data frame, they can easily be eliminated by using the extract operator on the tidy data, or dropping columns from the messy data frame prior to using `gather()`.

Note that I chose to leave the totals in the output data frame because almost all of the data in the screen capture represented totals of one form or another (i.e. only 2 of the 30 cells of data in the OP screen capture were not totals), and eliminating this data would make it difficult to confirm that the script worked correctly.

The solution can be extended to cover age categories referenced in the OP but not illustrated in the spreadsheet by adding appropriate column names to `theCols` vector, and by changing the `range=` argument in the `read_excel()` function that reads the bulk of the spreadsheet.

## UPDATE: reading multiple quarters from a specific worksheet

On November 29th the original poster modified the question to explain that there were multiple worksheets in the Excel file, one for each year.  This is easily handled with the following modifications.

1. Specify a worksheet with the `sheet=` parameter
2. Add `_Q1` to distinguish each quarter's read, and save the quarter as a key variable
3. Set worksheet names to years

The resulting tidy data will have year and quarter columns. Note that I updated my Excel workbook with dummy data so worksheets representing different years have different data so the results are distinguishable.

```
# download file from github to make script completely reproducible

sourceFile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/stackoverflowanswers/master/data/soQuestion53446800.xlsx"
destinationFile <- "./soQuestion53446800.xlsx"
download.file(sourceFile,destinationFile,mode="wb")

# set constants 
typeOfLeave <- "sick"
group <- "self employed"
year <- "2018"

# setup column names using underscore so we can separate key column into Sex, Age, and Quarter columns 
# after using rep() to build data with required repeating patterns, avoiding manual typing of all the column names 
sex <- rep(c("both","women","men"),16)
age <- rep(c(rep("all",3),rep("up to 17",3),rep("18 to 64",3),rep("65 and over",3)),4)
quarter <- c(rep("Q1",12),rep("Q2",12),rep("Q3",12),rep("Q4",12))
data.frame(sex,age,quarter) %>% unite(excelColNames) -> columnsData
theCols <- unlist(c("Country",columnsData["excelColNames"]))

theData <- read_excel(destinationFile,sheet=year,range="A5:AW9",col_names=theCols)

# use tidyr / dplyr to transform the data
theData %>% gather(.,key="key",value="Amount",2:49) %>% separate(.,key,into=c("Sex","Age","Quarter"),sep="_") -> tidyData

# assign constants

tidyData$typeOfLeave <- typeOfLeave
tidyData$group <- group
tidyData$year <- year

tidyData
```

...and the output, reading from the 2018 sheet in the workbook.

```
> tidyData
# A tibble: 240 x 8
   Country    Sex   Age   Quarter Amount typeOfLeave group         year 
   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>
 1 Total      both  all   Q1        2100 sick        self employed 2018 
 2 Afganistan both  all   Q1        2100 sick        self employed 2018 
 3 Albania    both  all   Q1        2100 sick        self employed 2018 
 4 Algeria    both  all   Q1        2100 sick        self employed 2018 
 5 Andora     both  all   Q1        2100 sick        self employed 2018 
 6 Total      women all   Q1         900 sick        self employed 2018 
 7 Afganistan women all   Q1         900 sick        self employed 2018 
 8 Albania    women all   Q1         900 sick        self employed 2018 
 9 Algeria    women all   Q1         900 sick        self employed 2018 
10 Andora     women all   Q1         900 sick        self employed 2018 
# ... with 230 more rows
>
```

If we change the configuration parameters we can read the 2017 data from the workbook I posted to Github.

```
# read second worksheet to illustrate multiple reads 

# set constants 
typeOfLeave <- "sick"
group <- "self employed"
year <- "2017"

theData <- read_excel(destinationFile,sheet=year,range="A5:AW9",col_names=theCols)

# use tidyr / dplyr to transform the data
theData %>% gather(.,key="key",value="Amount",2:49) %>% separate(.,key,into=c("Sex","Age","Quarter"),sep="_") -> tidyData

# assign constants

tidyData$typeOfLeave <- typeOfLeave
tidyData$group <- group
tidyData$year <- year

tidyData
```

...and the output:

```
> tidyData
# A tibble: 240 x 8
   Country    Sex   Age   Quarter Amount typeOfLeave group         year 
   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>
 1 Total      both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
 2 Afganistan both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
 3 Albania    both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
 4 Algeria    both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
 5 Andora     both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
 6 Total      women all   Q1       15000 sick        self employed 2017 
 7 Afganistan women all   Q1       15000 sick        self employed 2017 
 8 Albania    women all   Q1       15000 sick        self employed 2017 
 9 Algeria    women all   Q1       15000 sick        self employed 2017 
10 Andora     women all   Q1       15000 sick        self employed 2017 
# ... with 230 more rows
>
```

## Pulling it all together...

At this point we have built the basic ideas into a script that completely reads one worksheet. If we modify the code slightly and incorporate a function such as `lapply()`, we can start with a vector of worksheet names, read the files, convert them to tidy data format, and combine the files into a single tidy data set with `do.call()` and `rbind()`.

```
## version that combines multiple years into a single narrow format tidy data file
# download file from github to make script completely reproducible

sourceFile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/stackoverflowanswers/master/data/soQuestion53446800.xlsx"
destinationFile <- "./soQuestion53446800.xlsx"
download.file(sourceFile,destinationFile,mode="wb")


library(readxl)
library(tidyr)

# set constants
years <- c("2017","2018")
typeOfLeave <- "sick"
group <- "self employed"

# setup column names using underscore so we can separate key column into Sex, Age, and Quarter columns 
# after using rep() to build data with required repeating patterns, avoiding manual typing of all the column names 
sex <- rep(c("both","women","men"),16)
age <- rep(c(rep("all",3),rep("up to 17",3),rep("18 to 64",3),rep("65 and over",3)),4)
quarter <- c(rep("Q1",12),rep("Q2",12),rep("Q3",12),rep("Q4",12))
data.frame(sex,age,quarter) %>% unite(excelColNames) -> columnsData
theCols <- unlist(c("Country",columnsData["excelColNames"]))


lapply(years,function(x){
  theData <- read_excel(destinationFile,sheet=x,range="A5:AW9",col_names=theCols)

  # use tidyr / dplyr to transform the data
  theData %>% gather(.,key="key",value="Amount",2:49) %>% separate(.,key,into=c("Sex","Age","Quarter"),sep="_") -> tidyData

  # assign constants

  tidyData$typeOfLeave <- typeOfLeave
  tidyData$group <- group
  tidyData$year <- x

  tidyData
}) %>% do.call(rbind,.) -> combinedData
```

...and the output, demonstrating that the `combinedData` data frame includes data from both 2017 and 2018 worksheets.

```
> head(combinedData)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  Country    Sex   Age   Quarter Amount typeOfLeave group         year 
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>
1 Total      both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
2 Afganistan both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
3 Albania    both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
4 Algeria    both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
5 Andora     both  all   Q1       33000 sick        self employed 2017 
6 Total      women all   Q1       15000 sick        self employed 2017 
> tail(combinedData)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  Country    Sex   Age         Quarter Amount typeOfLeave group         year 
  <chr>      <chr> <chr>       <chr>    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>
1 Andora     women 65 and over Q4        2300 sick        self employed 2018 
2 Total      men   65 and over Q4        2400 sick        self employed 2018 
3 Afganistan men   65 and over Q4        2400 sick        self employed 2018 
4 Albania    men   65 and over Q4        2400 sick        self employed 2018 
5 Algeria    men   65 and over Q4        2400 sick        self employed 2018 
6 Andora     men   65 and over Q4        2400 sick        self employed 2018 
>
```

Comment: I should probably mention that in one sheet I have 49 variables. The screenshot presents just one of 4 quarters. The variable theDates should store a list of 4 dates. I will try tomorrow swiftly create a unique list of variables name and maybe use gather, will it work?

screen: https://imgur.com/a/KtEsZ9k

Comment: Are subsequent quarters in rows below the first table, or are they in columns to the right of the data in the screenshot? Also, you’ll need to use a different technique than assigning theDates as a vector of four different dates. Update your question to more accurately describe the structure of data in the worksheet and I can update my answer to read it correctly.

Comment: The subsequent quarters are right of the data in the screenshot. I will update more details tomorrow.

Comment: @Michel - I'll take a look at this over the weekend.

Comment: @Michel - see my updated answer. Please accept it if you found it helpful.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Many thanks for helping me to understand the problem!